# If Xpath is not found my script not moving to other test cases and stop everything and exit. I am using selenium testng frame work

Tags: selenium

```
//getElementByXPath function for static xpath
public WebElement getElementByXPath(String Key){
    try{
        //This block will find element using Key value from web page and return It.
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(Object.getProperty(Key)));
    }catch(Throwable t){
        //If element not found on page then It will return null.
        Add_Log.debug("Object not found for key --"+Key);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here when some element is not found, my script stop and exit. But I want it just give me error so I can use it in test result and move to next test case.

Comment: Can you say what is "Object.getProperty(Key)"? Please give us value of that.

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to use the returned element from getElementByXPath in another method and when the element is not found, a null pointer exception is thrown ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommned using a webelement variable to store the result and then define return it... Sorry im not good at Java.

Some thing like this.

```
//getElementByXPath function for static xpath
public WebElement getElementByXPath(String Key){
try{
    //This block will find element using Key value from web page and return It.
    WebElement  xpathElem = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Object.getProperty(Key)));
   if(xpathElem != null)
   {
    return xpathElem; 
    }
    else
    {
      Add_Log.debug("Object not found for key --"+Key);
      return null;
    } 
 }catch(Throwable t){
    //If element not found on page then It will return null.
    Add_Log.debug("Object not found for key --"+Key);
    return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you say what is "Object.getProperty(Key)"? Means what it returns?

Comment: Im Sorry i dont know that. I have just used the Code the Questioner has pur there and suggested the output as per his/her expetation

Answer (score 0):

As you are using try/catch, when ever exception is came it is handled by catch block. if you want to throw this same exception after log statement then you can try like this

```
 public WebElement getElementByXPath(String Key){
        try{
            //This block will find element using Key value from web page and return It.
            return driver.findElement(By.xpath(Object.getProperty(Key)));
        }catch(Throwable t){
            //If element not found on page then It will return null.
            Add_Log.debug("Object not found for key --"+Key);

            //error message is thrown as exception which will appear in testng reports generally if you are using
            throw new Exception(t.getMessage());
        }
    }
```